# wxwidgets slider labels messed up (C++)

Tags: c++, macos, slider, wxwidgets

I'm creating a wxSlider in the simplest possible way:

```
  wxSlider *yma = new wxSlider(this,wxID_ANY,0,0,50,wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize,wxSL_VALUE_LABEL);
```

and it basically doesn't work; when I slide the slider, the associated "value" goes through a series of alphabetically (not numerically) sorted values and ends at 5.  (5 also appears near the end of the slider, at the correct location.)  The max/min values are also shown as 0 (correct) and 5 (not correct).  (Actually, the whole thing is sort of incorrect -- I thought wxSL_VALUE_LABEL would turn off the max/min labels, but it doesn't.)

I get the same behavior if I go to the samples distributed with wxWidgets and compile the widgets sample.  I'm on a Mac running Catalina, so everything is clang 11.0.3. The sample I compiled was from wxWidgets 3.0.1, building in a dedicated directory.  The version where I build my own slider is using 3.0.5.1_1, according to brew.

Any help?

Comment: so I presume you didn't compile the library yourself, but installed from `Homebrew`. But the sample you tried is from a different version of the library? If you can reproduce the label cut-off in the sample of the same version of the library as your application than it might be a bug and you should file it at trac.wxwidgets.org

Comment: This appears to be a Catalina issue.  As far as I can tell, wxWidgets and Catalina is a total mess.  I was eventually able to compile 3.1.4 (and everything appears to work), but no earlier version.

Comment: yes, for Catalina you need at least 3.1.3 (especially if you want the Dark Mode support). And it is easy to compile it: `cd wxWidgets-3.1.4 && mkdir buildMac && cd buildMac && ../configure --enable-debug && make` Did you have any issues doing that? And then for the sample just do: `cd wxWidgets-3.1.4/buildMac/samples/widgets && make`.

Comment: yes, I had lots of bizarre issues compiling it.  I also needed --disable-shared and, most bizarre of all, this line in the Makefile failed: `(if test -f utils/wxrc/Makefile ; then cd utils/wxrc && $(MAKE) all ; fi)` because the test succeeded and then the cd failed!  I had to cd into utils/wxrc, do the make by hand, and then move the Makefile out of the way so that the test -f would fail!  But once I did that, things seemed to work as expected.

Comment: Why do you need `--disable-shared`? It is best to use dynamic (AKA weak) lining on *nix/OSX, especially considering release cycle of OSX is not the same as wxWIdgets. And so SDK increase may make your program fail.

Comment: you just need to do `../configure --enable-debug && make`

Comment: OK.  I went back and just did --enable-debug.  Same failure as in the --disable-shared case surrounding utils/wxrc and the same fix "corrected" it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the stable releases of wxWidgets don't work with Catalina; you have to use 3.1.3 or later (as per Igor's comment above).